# "No method 'setAutoResize'" when trying to resize canvas

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas, sdk

Let's start from the beginning.

**The situation:**

I have an app. When I go to the app searching by name (smart city project) from the Facebook main search bar, I see the app loaded inside Facebook, and a single scroll bar to navigate the content (https://apps.facebook.com/smartcityproject/). All OK here.

When I go to the page (https://www.facebook.com/smartCanada) and click the app tab, it takes me to the app inside Facebook too, but this Facebook context is diferent (https://www.facebook.com/smartCanada/app_253415468099353). Here we have a main scroll from Facebook, and a inner scroll from the page iframe.

**The problem:**

**I must get only one scroll.**

The documentation (and several posts, blogs and forums) says I can use FB.Canvas.setSize or setAutoGrow (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/), but I get the following javascript error from using those methods:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setAutoResize'
```

in file connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js, line 74

**Questions:**

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? That 'setAutoResize' method souldn't be in Facebook libraries? I must wait some script to load? Is the method actually working or it isn't? Is there another way to change that iframe height?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your script stops working when it comes to this block of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userLanguage = '';

    window.fbAsyncInit = function(){

        // ...

        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();

        // ...
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    // ...
</script>
```

`FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();` is deprecated by now, so the JavaScript throws an error. You need to replace this line with `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();`, or remove it.

Also there's a second error in your script, when it comes to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    }
</script>
```

Change it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    })
    // Closing brace was missing!!
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, you are so right! The first one was the problem!

I thought there was no line trying to resize the height, so I added the second one but it was not working, and the Chrome debugger doesn't show me the stacktrace from the first error, so I thought the problem was inside the Facebook library :s

Thank you very very much. This was driving me crazy!